# Debugging with Visual Studio Code to WSL2 remotely then using a virtual Conda environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, vscode-debugger, wsl-2

I stumbled upon an issue while i try to use the VS Code to remote debug WSL2 that is using an Conda virtual environment. When i use the 'base' version of Conda the debugger starts properly. But for the virtual environment it just kinda "blinks" with the debug bar and then stops.

GIF Sequence of the issue here i start with the virtual environment then switch to the base

[image: 1]

This is my launch.json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "run",
            "justMyCode":true,
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/marten/rl/go-explore/robustified"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems the issue had nothing to do with WSL or Conda, but instead the Python module that needed to be downgraded to use Python 3.6

[link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19441)